# How can I work with Java string arrays?

Tags: java

I have a String Array. Whenever I fetch an Array, I get data like this

```
[Alex Jones, Robert Flip, Farabi Fahim]
```

Now, my question is

1. Is possible to remove `[]` from the result?
2. How can I progrmatically format names like this `A.Jones, R.Flip & F.Fahim` from result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can format the names in the way you describe with something like:

```
System.out.println("Alex Jones".replaceAll("^(\\w)\\w+", "$1."));
```

```
A. Jones
```

As for your first question, that should just be a simple `substring` call: `arrayString.substring(1, arrayString.length() - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

To get Alex Jones out of the array, use `names[0]`.

```
private String fixName(String name)
{
   //break into name and last name
   int whiteIndex = name.indexOf(' ');
   String newName = name.substring(0, 1) + "." + name.substring(whiteIndex, name.length);

   return newName;
}

public static void main()
{
 String[] names = whateverYouUseToGetNames();
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
 for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
      System.out.println(fixName(names[i]));

}
```